# jquery convert variable inside dynamic function to hardcode value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a dynamic function that gets attached to multiple textarea's when the page loads. How would I convert a variable to its text value during runtime so its value shows as text in the dom?
This works below and is what I see when I inspect the event.
fyi, currentPlayerQuestions is a json.

```
     $("#question_" + currentPlayerQuestions["QuestionGuid"]).on('blur', function (e) {

           alert($("#" + "question_" + currentPlayerQuestions["Answer"]).val());


 });
```

But what I want in the dom is the following:

```
     $("#question_" + currentPlayerQuestions["QuestionGuid"]).on('blur', function (e) {

           alert($("#" + "question_12345134132").val());


 });
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: If your code works, what's the issue?

Comment: @raduation it's complex, but long story short, it's a signlar app and I'm trying to be clever and save a lot of info from going across the wire and one easy way to it is to just have the ability to convert the variable to actual text in the dom inside this function. Can it be done ? This works fine outside of the function. var answer = $("<td><input id=" + "\"answer_" + currentPlayerQuestions["QuestionGuid"] + "\"" + "type=\"text\"  class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"answer\" /></td>");

Comment: Are you trying to inject `answer` into the DOM?  If so, use something like `$('#container').append(answer);`.  If you are trying to set the text of a DOM element, do `$('#container').text(myVar);`.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @raduation. I am trying to inject answer into the dom. but not into a container. I want to inject into into a dynamic function.